# What is improved in iPhone 6 Face Detection

Tags: ios, face-detection, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

[Apple's description of the iPhone 6](https://www.apple.com/iphone-6/cameras/) includes this text

> **Improved face detection**
>
> The iSight camera now recognizes faces faster
>   and more accurately — even those farther away or in a crowd — for
>   better portraits and group shots. And it improves blink and smile
>   detection and selection of faces in burst mode to automatically
>   capture your best shots.

I've used iOS face detection before, both from Core Graphics ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_detect_faces/ci_detect_faces.html)) and AVFoundation ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataFaceObject_Class/index.html)). I see no mention in those libraries of improvements for iPhone 6, or elsewhere in Apple literature.

My app is showing near-identical detection times for both libraries running on an iPhone 6.

Is there any documentation on this "improved face detection"? Specifically, is this updates to the existing libraries or something new that should be included?